# adb copy file from /sdcard/ to /data/data/package without root permission

Tags: android, adb

I connect my android device to PC and connect through adb. What I want to do is copy a file from my PC to the internal storage of my app (`/data/data/com.example.app/databases`) without root or `su`. I first push the file from my PC to the `/sdcard/` folder of my android device.

```
adb push database.sqlite /sdcard/
```

Then I want to copy that file to the internal storage of my app. I can succesfully run-as my app package and see the internal storage.

```
adb shell
$ run-as com.example.app
$ ls databases
```

This causes no permission issues. I can also view the `/sdcard/` folder if i do not use `run-as`  with no problem

```
adb shell
$ ls sdcard
```

The problem is that when I first use `run-as` I do not have access to /sdcard/ folder, and when I do not use `run-as` I can not access the internal storage folder. So, if I execute `run-as` and then execute this:

```
cp /sdcard/database.sqlite /data/data/com.example.app/databases/
```

I get this permission denied error:

```
cp: /data/data/com.example.app/databases/database.sqlite: Permission denied
```

I also tried withh dd but did not work:

```
dd if=/sdcard/database.sqlite of=/data/data/com.example.app/databases/
# output
dd: /sdcard/database.sqlite: Permission denied
```

How can I solve this problem? I have no root access nor superuser (`su`). I think I can achieve this without root because using android studio device file explorer I managed to upload the database in the same android device. I just want to do this using command line (Windows).

Any help would be appreciated :D

Comment: "The problem is that when I first use run-as I do not have access to /sdcard/ folder" -- did your app needs to request `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in the manifest and at runtime? If not, your app's user account does not have access to external storage. Note that none of this will work on Android 10+, due to the new restrictions on external storage.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for the suggestion. I already have the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in the manifest, however I do not request it at runtime. Can this be the problem?

Comment: @CommonsWare I also enabled the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` from the android device, but the issue remains. What is weird is that I get permission denied for the internal storage folder, not the sdcard path (I updated my question with the exact error message)

Comment: manifest permissions are no longer sufficient since Android 6. So that's most likely the culprit in your case.

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski so what should I try? Do you know anything I can do to solve my problem?

Comment: As already told you need to support runtime permissions. Google it up - there's a lot of libs that can help you with that. Manifest perms are obsolete

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski The external storage permission is enabled for my app (I checked in the app settings). But still when I use adb I get the errors posted on my question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My suggestion is to use a different approach while copying database file into the app's private area.

In particular, you can copy the file into `/data/local/tmp` with:

```
adb push database.sqlite /data/local/tmp
```

and then copy/move the db file into the app's `databases` folder with:

```
adb shell run-as com.example.app cp /data/local/tmp/database.sqlite databases
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much ! This solved my problem !!!
Just for clarification, the second command (`adb run-as ...`) couldn't work as it is (`unknown command run-as`), but I added `shell` and it worked. The command now is: `adb shell run-as com.example.app cp /data/local/tmp/database.sqlite databases`

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution similar as Lino answer

```
adb shell rm -rf /sdcard/[CLONE_FODER]/
adb push ./[YOUR_FOLDER]/[YOUR_FILE] /sdcard/CLONE_FODER/. 
adb shell run-as com.android.example cp -r /sdcard/CLONE_FODER/YOUR_FILE /data/data/com.android.example/databases
```

Comment: What does this add to the existing answer?